# How can I solve these OMEdit errors?

Tags: error-handling, openmodelica

## I need some help to solve to errors,

**1. Library and version error**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzNA9.png)

I got some libraries from internet in order to model several systems and study more about this program. But, for the ThermoPower library, everytime I launce OMEdit, I got this message. And sometimes I also get some library loading problems and I think this is related with this message box.
I assmumed that this is because of openmodelica's version but I don't know exactly why and what to do.

**
2. Error during running exmaples**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oa2Ip.png)

This is message browser's capture when I run example model from ThermoSysPro Guidebook's example.
I assumed it was because of initial conditions, so I tried to examine components and understand which
variables are missing. However, as I examine more and more, I found out that it's almost impossible for me to diagnose every problamatic points only by myself. So here's two things I'm curious about this problem.

1. Assuming from this message, is this error casued by initial value?
2. Is there any OpenModelica examples related to steam cycles or thermo-hydraulics for beginner?

I'm having so much troubles for studying this opensource program alone. Please help little lost lamb... Thank you for time.

I tried some things to solve both problems.

1st prob: I tried to re-install the library but I noticed it is no use just reinstalling. I've seen similar circumstances in the net and tried some to use tortoise SVN but failed.

2nd prob: I tried to study from ThermoSysPro guidelines and this is the part I was working on.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNFRS.png)

I tried to understand related equations and check the libraries so the equations are well positioned and working. But I was so confused with massive length of code and I decided to ask for some help.

Comment: Please don't ask multiple (very different) questions in one Stack Overflow question but open multiple ones. I answered the first part, but don't know about the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Answering only question 1:

Regarding the load error message of ThermoPower it's telling you that you already have Modelica libraries loaded with some specific version, but ThermoPower needs a different version of these libraries. For example ThermoPower 3.1.0 needs the Modelica Standard Library version 3.2.3, but OMEdit loads version 4.0.0.

```
Scripting Warning
ThermoPower requested package Modelica of version 3.2.3. Modelica 4.0.0 is used instead which states that it is only compatible with a conversion script. Use convertPackageToLibrary(ThermoPower, Modelica, "4.0.0") to run the conversion script or proceed with potential issues as a result.
```

You can do `Unload all & Reload ThermoPower` to load all correct versions of the dependencies of ThermoPower.

If you are always working with a library that needs another library version you can change what libraries OMEdit loads on startup: Tools->Options->Libraries

[image: OMEdit Options Libraries]